# how to validate datepicker date in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

```
<div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
<input type="text" class="form-control" readonly name="start" required>
<span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn default" type="button" >
<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button></span> </div>
```

how to create validate datepicker bootsrap?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your datepicker like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker").blur(function(){
        val = $(this).val();
        val1 = Date.parse(val);
        if (isNaN(val1) == true && val !== ''){
           alert("error");
        }
        else{
           console.log(val1);
        }
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/251/)

Comment: i have tried,but when i click button submit to save data, alert required datepicker not show when datepicker empty.